# How To Parse Date From any datetime format to dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, format

i want to parse any datetime format to dd/MM/yyyy format.

here is my code

```
// dates i am providing are
// Sat, 01 Oct 2011 17:30:00 +0400
// and
// Sat, 01 October   2011 12:21:23 EST

Datetime  dt = Convert.toDateTime(pubDate);
```

which is giving me following exception

**The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 32**

any one guide me how can i parse any dateformat to a single one?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For anything that DateTime.Parse doesn't handle, you'll have to try custom format strings.  http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/parsing-dates-when-aspnets-datetimeparse-doesnt-work/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the 'EST' from the string and it should work.

Comment: That's kind of important information, especially if the goal is to convert to UTC.

Comment: ok, could you please guide me it will be EST always or any other value can come here too?

Comment: @Joe Agreed. I figured this fell under the heading of 'any help' though... :)

Comment: the EST is the timezone, it could vary.

Comment: @UMAR I am looking for a more consistent answer for you, but I do know (in my experience) that the DateTime parser doesn't handle timezones correctly, hence why removing 'EST' helps...

Comment: yes it is working by removing time zone value but i cant hard code it. if time zone vary then again exception will raise.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` doesn't store dates in a "format" - it uses an internal representation. You need to *parse* a passed in string in order to get the correct value for the `DateTime` and when you want to *display* it you can then format it to whatever display.

Your best bet is to use [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) supplying it with the exact format string. You need to use the [custom Date and Time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) with it.

Use the overload that takes a `string[]` of format strings - one for each date format.

In regards to the `EST` portion - the framework doesn't have support for named timezones. You may want to write a wrapper that converts named timezones to their equivalent but parseable form.

Untested (based on MSDN example):

```
string[] formats= {"ddd, dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss K", 
                   "ddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss EST"};

DateTime dateValue;

foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
{
   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                              DateTimeStyles.None, 
                              out dateValue))
      Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
   else
      Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date.", dateString);
}
```